# Correct formula to "invert" rotation (in degrees) in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, degrees

I have my player movieclip on the stage, and when the mouse is clicked a bullet is fired and projected at the correct angle to point itself at the mouse location. I also want a "mirroring" enemy, that fires at the complete opposite direction when the player does.

For example, when the player shoots upwards, the enemy should shoot down. Likewise, shooting to the right will cause the enemy to shoot to the left.

Is there a formula to convert the rotation in degrees to it's complete opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Matrix is a very simple and exact solution. just multiple a or c with -1 ( to flip vertical and horizontal ).

Sample code:

```
        var _tmpMatrix:Matrix = sprite.transform.matrix;
        _tmpMatrix.a *= -1;
        if ( _tmpMatrix.a < 0 ) {
            _tmpMatrix.tx = sprite.width + sprite.x;
        } else {
            _tmpMatrix.tx = 0;
        }
        sprite.transform.matrix = _tmpMatrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't adding or subtracting 180 degrees point in the opposite direction?

Comment: I tried that initially, but it seemed to change the rotation based on where the enemy was (which I countered), but to no avail.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct values when doing the calcuations, some functions in AS3 want angles in radians instead of degrees, you might have to convert from degrees to radians etc.

Answer (score -1):

or

obj.scaleX = -1;

will do the same thing. =)

Comment: It's not very clear what you are saying. After all, scaling the object negatively will have a myriad of undesirable effects. Flipping the rotation won't work either. Can you add detail?